# Can't add css_class to existing layout block in Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm trying to add a CSS class name to a Layout block in Magento2.  It's for the *My Orders* link in the top `.header.panel` nav.

So far I've tried...

```
<referenceBlock name="company-customer-account-navigation-orders-link" htmlClass="hide-on-desktop" />
```

&

```
<referenceBlock name="company-customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">hide-on-desktop</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Neither of these work, is it at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

`htmlClass` only works with containers, it does not work with blocks.

If you check [this dev docs page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html) you'll see `htmlClass` is only mentioned under containers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using container to get it work. For example,

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
      <container name="header.wrap" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-wrap">
        <container name="header.top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-top">
          <!-- Top Bar -->
          <container name="header.main.topbar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-topbar" before="-">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/topbar.phtml"/>
          </container>
        </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```